# How to add a class' function to the overload resoution list within the other function of the same class?

Tags: c++, namespaces, overload-resolution, argument-dependent-lookup, name-lookup

The question is within the code snippet:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>


struct A {
    static int max(std::pair<int, int> const& pair) {
        return std::max(pair.first, pair.second);
    }

    int use_max(std::pair<int, int> const & p, int const i) {
        // 1) The following works fine:
        // return std::max(i, max(p));

        // 2) The following also works fine:
        // using std::max;
        // return max(i, this->max(p));

        // 3) This does not compile, afaiu cause the A::max did
        // not even got into the overload resolution list due to
        // name look up rules.
        using std::max;
        return max(i, max(p));

        // Question: What do I write here to add A::max into the
        // overload resolution list, e.g., something like:
        // using std::max;
        // using A::max;
        // return max(i, max(p));
    }

};

int main() {
    std::cout << A().use_max(std::make_pair(2, 3), 1);
}
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? No matter what overloads are considered the call inside `use_max` will always call the same function. Why do you care what overloads are considered when anyhow only one is called?

Answer (score 0):

`using A::max;` is not possible since `A` is a class and not a namespace.

And the answer to your query is simple:

`return max(i, A::max(p));`

I am not sure what else are you hoping to achieve here.

Update: Thought about it some more and you can modify code this way?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
struct B {
    static int max(int A, int B)
    {
        return std::max(A,B);
    }
};
struct A:B{
    static int max(std::pair<int, int> const& pair) {
        return std::max(pair.first, pair.second);
    }
    using B::max;
    int use_max(std::pair<int, int> const & p, int const i) {
        return max(i, max(p));
    }
};
int main() {
    std::cout << A().use_max(std::make_pair(2, 3), 1);
}
```